# Add id for rows in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datatable

I am using Datatable plugin. I am fetching data from server side. Now I want to assign unique id to each row. How do I do that?

It would be better if I can assign id from client side(by setting any option or property of datatable I guess).

Thanks.

Comment: May be this will help you https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId

Comment: Do you mean a PK field which is also AI (Auto Increment) ?

Comment: @OhadM I do not want new field. I just want to assign unique id to each row.(without using data source property if possible).

Comment: It is exactly what I have described to you - The PK on your first field will be assigned with AI (Auto increment) and this will will assure that each row will be unique.

Comment: @OhadM Ok I just want a unique id on each row. I don't fully understand the PK you are suggesting but want to try that. So how do I apply that?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp - PK and
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html - AI. 
I would explain to you how to achieve PK & AI but I am not sure which DBMS you are using.

Comment: I'm using mongodb. Btw I have email id field which is unique and I am using it as a row ID and that works fine, but I want client side ID assignment for rows(if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: '/api/staff',
    rowId: 'staffId'
} );
```

Here `staffId` is `property` from your data source.

Please check [Document](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId)

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Thanks again.

Comment: This worked but isn't there any way that datatable create id client side and assign it to row, so that I do not have to use my server side(data source) variable for assigning id?